# Localhost Error (403 Forbidden) with Yosemite

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403, osx-yosemite, user.config

First, I looked on this page [[Apache localhost 403 error with Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250566/apache-localhost-403-error-with-yosemite?answertab=oldest#tab-top][1]) because the person seems to have the same problem as me. I tried differents things but its doesn't work for me. When I write localhost in my url I receive a `403 Forbidden "You don't have permission to access / on this server"`. Sorry, I'm an beginner. I don't really know what kind of informations that you need to know to help me to fix that.

My directory /Users/schan/Sites/
My user.conf (schan.conf) is

```
<Directory "/Users/schan/Sites/">
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My httpd.conf (some informations tell me if you need more)

```
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/Users/schan/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/schan/Sites">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 2):

If you write 'localhost' in your url, the following directory is called on yosemite: /Library/WebServer/Documents/
which is not the same as /Users/schan/Sites
you would call /Users/schan/Sites using:

```
http://localhost/~schan
```

Getting a 403 on 'localhost' on my Yosemite happens, if i drop the read-permission from the Documents Folder, it should be 644 or, in Finder Info it would say

```
System    read and write
wheel     read only
everyone  read only
```

For setting up the local user, i found this link the most helpful and complete: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/