# How to point URL to directory?

Tags: linux, apache, hosting

I need to point web url's like

```
http://example.com/subdir1
http://example.com/subdir2
```

to same directory

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/default/
```

on Linux hosting (Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2) - how to do that, please?

Comment: You may want to provide details of which web server you are using

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on VPS and Apache2

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you, will ask there, but maybe it can be solved using .httaccess rewrite rules so I hoping that someone will post some idea.

Comment: This can be done by setting the `DocumentRoot` for both virtual host in a configuration file located under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and then enable the configuration by executing `a2ensite <configuration>`. Read up on how to configure a virtual host for apache2. Here is a link that shows a basic setup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26490642/1047662

Comment: Yes it works  using

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
  Alias /subdir1 "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/default" 
</IfModule>

but I can not access vhost.conf each time so the question is - how to write that using .htaccess, please?