# cannot connect to localhost after installing yosemite

Tags: php, macos, apache, unix, osx-yosemite

I am trying to connect to localhost and I am getting the following error on the browsers (chrome and ff and safari)

> Browsers connection attempt to localhost was rejected.

i tried

> telnet 127.0.0.1
>
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

and

> Barry$ / : curl localhost
>
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

the `httpd.conf` is set to `LISTEN : 80`

However I can connect using thin on `localhost:3000` for a rails project

I've looked at other similar Q's and answers but cannot find a fix.

Comment: well, if it's set to listen to 80, why do you expect it to connect on 3000?

Comment: ...by the way, don't you think this is a question for [http://serverfault.com/](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: I dont im just saying that connection works for 3000

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood... i still think this question has a better place on server fault...

Comment: ill try there if i cant get an answer here

Comment: ive seen similar q's posted here though

Comment: @webeno No, this is not a server fault question

Comment: Maybe try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583859/apache-localhost-username-not-working

Comment: thanks but i saw this one already and its still not working. Looks like everyone is stumped on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post my solution to getting localhost working again.

I used the following process to reinstall apache and update the ports.
It worked for me so I hope it can help someone else.

I do mention at the bottom that im still getting an unfound url error, so if anyone can help, that would be great.

RE-BUILDING APACHE

**port search apache2**
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider using selfupdate

**sudo port uninstall apache2**

**sudo port -v selfupdate**

Ensure that Xcode command line tools are installed or else you get a warning:
Warning: The Xcode Command Line Tools don't appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.

**xcode-select —install**

**sudo port upgrade outdated**

**sudo port search apache2**

then i did a reinstall of apache2
**sudo port install apache2**

**sudo port load apache2**

This got Localhost back up and running on port 80 for me however I'm not out of the woods yet.
when i go to my dev sites  using

localhost/~barrymcmahon/

im getting the following error

**Not Found**

The requested URL /~barrymcmahon/php_5_advanced/ was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Apache config with this command:

```
sudo apachectl -t
```

This tests the config files and tells you if there's an error. Running sudo apachectl start does not output config file syntax errors to the logs for some reason.

Do u have skype or pow installed ?

Comment: httpd: Syntax error on line 527 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp5.so, 10): Symbol not found: _unixd_config\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so\n  Expected in: /usr/sbin/httpd\n in /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so

Comment: im sure ive seen this error before while localhost was working on mavericks

Comment: i dont have either installed but im looking at pow to see what it is