# Yosemite localhost displays 404, but computer name displays "It works!"

Tags: macos, apache, localhost, computer-name

I've been having a bit of a headache since upgrading to Yosemite. Typically, I run a gulp or grunt connect package that spawns a Node server on port 9000. I hit the page by going to http://localhost:9000. However, after firing up the server, that URL gives me a 404.

I ran $apachectl configtest and got the following:

*"AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using jake.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message"*

"jake.local" is my computer name. Coincidentally (or maybe not?), when I go to jake.local:9000, I get my website and no 404.

I'm not an Apache expert by any means, but I have followed this tutorial with no luck: [Apache localhost/~username/ not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583859/apache-localhost-username-not-working)... and have ended up just reverting my httpd.conf because the instructions won't work for me. I'm starting to think I might have a different issue, as it's my understanding that out of the box, Yosemite should just live me a "It Works!" when I hit http://localhost

I'm not sure how to proceed, but I'd like localhost to work again and not have to use my computer name. How would I go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:

127.0.0.1:9000 also gives me positive results. In my host file, I have:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of searching, I discovered there's a line in my hostfile leftover from Mavericks:

```
#in /etc/hosts

fe80::1%lo0  localhost
```

If you have that, remove it.