# Apache, MySql, dan PHP on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache, webserver

I am following this tutorial to setup my Mac as the web server: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/

But unfortunately I got stuck, if I access the http://localhost/~username/info.php it works normally, but when I access only: http://localhost/info.php it says forbidden, any idea how to fix this?

### Edit:

I want to access both the System root and User root
Big Thanks

Comment: It works because it's in your home directory and not the server root.

Comment: have a look at this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583859/apache-localhost-username-not-working

Comment: @jaysingkar, I tried the link you mentioned above but still not working, if I only access localhost said forbidden, but if I put localhost/~username it's work properly.

Comment: @user3573124 do you want to access both the URLs ?

Comment: @jaysingkar exactly, I want to able access for both URLs

Comment: Upvoted to bring back to zero. If people are going to vote down the question, please explain why.

Comment: Still not working any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think to achieve this, you would need to activate and use virtual host.
Try this:
1) Open httpd.conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

2) Look for followig line and uncomment it:

```
# Virtual hosts

Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

3) This will allow usage of the httpd-vhosts.conf file, open this file to add in the vhost.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

4) Add following code in the start of the file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Check if your configuration is correct by running this command `httpd -S`

Comment: I think, my setting is not correct, it show something like this:

Warning: DocumentRoot [/Library/WebServer/Documents/Sites/] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/Users/username/Sites/] does not exist

Sorry for this silly questions, how to fixed this?

Big Thanks

Comment: check if both directories exists. and in `[/Users/username/Sites/]` I think you would need to use your username instead of `username`. Also could you update your question with contents of `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the username with real name. I changed it but still access forbidden (screenshot link- https://postimg.org/image/ylhj1iirb/). 

following is my vhost: 
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/soetjitro/Sites/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>