# macOS Sierra 10.12.2 Apache not working

Tags: apache, macos-sierra

I've upgraded to the current version of macOS. I want to work with Apache. Well, my problem is, that when I try to access localhost with or without ~Username, I get an error message saying ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on Chrome or "Can't open Page" on Safari. Apache is running and apachectl configtest says "Syntax OK".

I placed the current version of phpMyAdmin into /Library/WebServer/Documents and tried to access it, same problem.

I followed the steps in this guide without a solution for me
[Apache localhost/~username/ not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583859/apache-localhost-username-not-working)

So does anyone know what problem I'm facing? I'm clueless right now.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is exactly. What have you tried, what happens? See also [mcve]

Comment: My Question is, if someone faced the same problem and if there is a workaround for it. I tried to reinstall Apache via homebrew, restart of my Mac and Apache itself. But nothing changed, I don't get at least the It works! page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same outcomes as above, using virtual hosts though, and after updating to macos 10.12.2 was receiving `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

My original setup is based on the excellent posts here: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-mysql-vhost-apc

And as such, because I'm using Homebrew, all I needed to do was also run `brew upgrade` on CLI followed by `sudo apachectl restart` and I'm back up and running.